# Different php result between terminal and browser

Tags: php, nginx

My server is running php-fpm with nginx. I had applied these permissions.

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data /usr/share/nginx/html
sudo chmod -R g+rw /usr/share/nginx/html
sudo chmod g+s /usr/share/nginx/html
```

I have this code.

```
if(function_exists("my_void_function")){

    echo "exist";

}else{
    echo "none exist";
}
```

I am getting different result that simple code. you can see screenshot of my pc from this image.

[image: php different result terminal and browser]

Comment: Is the function name really `my_void_function`?

Comment: Yeah. i added via custom php extension.

Comment: That explains it. See answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have added the function via a custom extension, you must load the extension with the respective `php.ini` file of the PHP engine. PHP CLI has a different php.ini than PHP-FPM/mod_php.

Also, after changing php.ini of PHP-FPM, you must restart the PHP-FPM service (usually `sudo service php-fpm restart` on Debian-like systems). Those who are using mod_php with Apache need to restart the Apache service.

Comment: thank you for your helping. I just added same ini file under /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d